# How did $f(x)=x^{3}+4x^{2}-10$ become $x = g(x) = x-\frac{x^{3}+4x^{2}-10}{3x^{2}+8x}$ in fixed point iteration?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

I was following these slides I found in Google since I couldn't understand my prof's lecture:
[https://www.math.ust.hk/~mamu/courses/231/Slides/ch02_2b.pdf](https://www.math.ust.hk/%7Emamu/courses/231/Slides/ch02_2b.pdf)

At slide 10, it shows five different transpositions of the function $f(x)=x^{3}+4x^{2}-10$. What I am interested in knowing is how did it get to $x = g(x) = x-\frac{x^{3}+4x^{2}-10}{3x^{2}+8x}$ since the root can be found within five iterations.

I assume that the denominator was determined from getting the first derivative of the numerator. ***Now, is this technique applicable to all cubic functions?***

I also tried plugging values like '1' into the x variables to initiate a self-check in case I'm stuck. However, it gives out different values. For example, substitute 1 into 'x' in $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10-x^{3}}$ gives $\frac{3}{2}$, whereas using '1' to the equation I'm interested in gave a different answer, $\frac{16}{11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind this is [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). It does apply to all differentiable functions, not just cubics.

The basic idea is, given a function $f(x)$ and a particular point $x_n$ with $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$ specified, we can approximate the function using its Taylor series as
$$
f(x) \approx f(x_n) + f'(x_n)(x - x_n)
$$
If we try to find the root of the function on the RHS, assuming $f'(x_n) \ne 0$, you get
$$
\begin{split}
f(x_n) + f'(x_0)(x - x_n) &= 0 \\
x - x_n &= \frac{-f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\
x &= x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
\end{split}
$$

Hence, we pick the next iteration $x_{n+1}$ as the RHS.

Comment: Oh. I get it. So, in return, I am applying another method of estimating a root. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be explained as a definition of $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n$ rather than a formula for $x$ in terms of $x_0$.

Comment: @J.G. of course, started with $x_n$ and ended with $x_0$ -- stupid typos...